# C open() directory no error

Tags: c, fcntl

I have a function that opens file then read theses files, with the standard open() et read() functions. I use the errno variables for all possible errors such as permission denied or no such file or directory, but when I use open on a directory it don't return a error it simply open it and try to read it. 
So how can I get an error message when I give open a directory ?

Comment: Use `fstat()` on the file-descriptor you get from `open()`?

Comment: A code example would eliminate the assumption under which I provide an answer ... because errno is not initialised by the open function, nor is it changed when it returns successfully; errno is set only when an error occurs. It is up to you to set errno before calling open(), if that is what you need to do.

Comment: Always remember the Unix philosophy: "Everything is a file".

Comment: You don't give your operating system.  Using `open()` (mangled to `_open()`) with a directory name on Windows gives an EACCES error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't wanted to use anything else as read and write, I found that the error is returned at using **read()** not by *open()*

Answer (score 2):

Directory is also a file (In terms of Unix/Linux). So generally you won't get an error. You can use [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) function for tracking of ordinary or special files.

When you use either stat or fstat, you need to declare a struct stat variable like `struct stat var`. The `stat` structure has a member called `st_mode` which has the information of what kind of file it is.

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

Comment: Using `stat()` rather than `fstat()` opens up a potential time-of-check vs. time-of-use (TOCTOU) race.

Answer (score 1):

Directory also a file in Unix*, if you want to avoid to open a directory by `open()`, you may need to check the file type. As @nayabbashasayed say,you can use the `stat` to check the file type and more info.

Here is an example code to check the type by `stat`:

```
const char  *filePath;
struct stat  fileStatBuf;
if(stat(filePath,&fileStatBuf) == -1){
     perror("stat");
     exit(1);
}

/*
 *You can use switch to check all
 *the types you want, now i just use 
 *if to check one.
*/
if((fileStatBuf.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR){
    printf("This type is directory\n");
}
```

Hope that can help you.